# Is there a way to disable Xamarin Forms SwipeGestureRecognizer on Desktop?

Tags: xamarin.forms, swipe-gesture

I have a Xamarin Forms app and I wonder if it's possible to allow SwipeGestureRecognizer only for Phones (or small screens).

I'm using a view with 2 content views. On Desktop I want to see both at screen, but on Phone I want to see them individually (swipe gesture).

```
        <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
            <SwipeGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SwipedViewCommand}" Direction="Right" />
        </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
```

The command inverts the value of a boolean, and each content view is visible binded to that boolean (one checking for true, the other one to false)

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/swipe

Comment: do you mean a Gesture you are adding to a view yourself, or an existing gesture that is built into a view?

Comment: sorry. I've updated the question. Could you check again?

Comment: use OnIdiom - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/consuming#onidiom-markup-extension

Comment: Yes, but how can I use onIdiom with SwipeGestureRecognizer?

Comment: not sure in XAML, I would probably do it in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue on XF: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8756

In the meantime, you can set `CanExecute` of `Command`:

`new Command(() => { }, () => Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone);`